# attach picture to email

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

Anyone knows how to attach images with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
```

I know how to do it with `Intent.ACTION_SEND`, but i would like to use `SENDTO` to remove the Bluetooth option for the user.

What i have works fine when not attaching the picture but when i use

```
intent.setData(pictureUri);
```

It tells me that there isn't any application to do the job.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**

Inserted the code that I have now. It "works fine" except that the image isn't getting attached.

Code

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
intent.setType("text/html");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mailto:?");
intent.setData(uri);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, picture);
intent.putExtra("subject", subject );
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via:"));
```

The `picture` is a Uri for a picture on the phone.

Anyone knows what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pic));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the API docs, SENDTO expects a recipient in the data field, not an attachment.
By saying `intent.setData(pictureUri)`, you're basically trying to send a message to the picture. [See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SENDTO).

SEND accepts attachments via extras, so you could try the same for SENDTO.

For example:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);
```

Comment: Just tried to use EXTRA_STREAM it goes through but nothing is attached